# Typescript - How to convert the string ("console.log") to the function (console.log)

Tags: javascript, typescript

Using typescript, I need to convert some strings like "Math.floor" and "console.log" to the functions Math.floor and console.log, in order to be able to use those functions when passed as a string parameter.

For example

```
applyFunction ("Math.floor", 4.2); // => Math.floor(4.2) => 4
applyFunction ("console.log", "Hi"); // => console.log("Hi") => Hi
```

And so on.

I tried adding them as keys and values in an object and scanning the object whenever needed. But since I don't have the time to continuously search for and add all existing Typescript functions, I'm looking for a more comprehensive approach.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

FWIW you can use [`eval()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval) to parse strings as code.

Example:

```js
eval("console.log('foo')")
```

That being said, I'd advice you to [be careful when using eval()](https://stackoverflow.com/a/86580/1814486).

Comment: For me it worked as:

eval("console.log")('foo');

Thanx alot

Answer (score 1):

If you are using the browser you can do:

```
window['Math']['floor'](4.2);
window['console']['log']('Hi');
```

Make sure you iterate over the namespaces, eval(string) works better.

Comment: I've posted an answer  below that uses `eval` but I like this one better

Comment: @NicholasKyriakides eval(string) does the work better, this one is just another approach it you are in the browser, but is difficult because you must iterate over namespaces

Comment: why is it difficult, simple split and reduce

Comment: eval('Math.floor')(4.2) was much easier for my situation. Thanks a lot

Comment: concerning espacarellos comment *"Math.floor".split(".").reduce((o,i)=>o[i],window)(5)*